# Change Name of iPhone Developer in Code Signing Identity

Tags: iphone

Please can anyone suggest me how can i change the name of iPhone Developer in Code signing identity in the project Build Settings. For example : its like :

iPhone Developer: My Name (Dfcvcvcv)

I want to change the 'My Name' in the above. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to generate a new signing identity with the new name

Comment: How can I do that please elaborate?

Comment: Go to the [provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action), there you can request a new signing identity. You may need a new Apple ID to get a new name.

Comment: Can it be done using the same account? Like if i edit the developer account holder's name somehow..then is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, look at the site, but you will have to generate the signing certificates again.

Comment: thanks.. please give it as an answer so that i can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of a developer can be changed by creating a new signing identity at the [provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action). You may want to create a new Developer ID and add it to the developer team.